# Sharepoint Javascript failing on page load

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am trying to get a list of schools to put in the `option` of a `select` element.  I would like the dropdown options to be added when the page loads but I am not doing something correct.  The below code works if a directly call it with a `button` element but it does not work on page load.

The error I get is "Object doesn't support this action" on the line `var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);`

```
var siteUrl= '/learning/schools';

window.load = init();

    function init(){

    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems());
}

function retrieveListItems() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);

    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Schools');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');

    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    var schoolCodes = document.getElementById('classSchoolList');

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var schoolOption = document.createElement('option');
        schoolOption.value = oListItem.get_item('Title');
        schoolOption.text = oListItem.get_item('Title') + " : " + oListItem.get_item('School');
        schoolCodes.add(schoolOption);
    }


}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

}
```

Comment: Your code seems right. May be you can try just function name as `retrieveListItems` without parentheses like below line : `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems);`. 
                                                                                                            Refer this : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79010/sharepoint-com-sp-clientcontextsiteurl-object-doesnt-support-this-action

Comment: @rohit I tried that but it still fails at the same point on page load. However I have a button that I click and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try

```
//load the sp.js script and execute the init method
//no guarantee sp.js will be fully loaded before init() runs.
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', init());

function init(){
    //ensure script is fully loaded, then execute retrieveListItems()
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems(), 'sp.js');
}
```

Or alternatively,

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', null, function(){
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems(), 'sp.js');
});
```

`ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` will wait for the 'sp.js' file to finish loading before calling `retrieveListItems()`. But if 'sp.js' hasn't been requested, it will wait forever. That's why we call `executeFunc` first to request 'sp.js'. Yet, it doesn't make any guarantees that it's loaded before moving on. It simply adds it to the stack of scripts that need to be loaded and then runs the callback.